# In Xamarin.Forms XAML, where should I store converter classes?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, converters

In the Xamarin.Forms app I'm working on, we use many converters within our XAML pages. Some of these converters are very specific to the view they operate in, while others are more generic (E.g., convert index to boolean based on input argument).

Is it best practice to store converter `.cs` files within the same folder as the view, or should they be consolidated in a separate root-level package/namespace?

Comment: There is no correct answer to this.  It’s a matter of opinion, style, project requirements, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice for storing converter classes can vary based on the specifics of your project and your team's preferences.

A converter could, however, be placed within the same folder as the view if it is only used within a single view. By doing so, other developers can find the converter more easily when they are working on the same view.

When a converter is used across multiple views or parts of the application, a separate root-level package or namespace may be more appropriate. By doing so, other developers can easily find and use the converter across applications, thus promoting code reuse.

The decision about where to store your converter classes ultimately depends on the needs, preferences, and reuse considerations of your project.